# Properties for interior and closure in metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-verification

I found the some following properties for general topology and prove these.

But, I want to verify that the proofs are really true.

Let $(X,d)$ be metric space. Let $A$ be any subset of $X$.

Define the interior of $A$ ($ int(A) $) and the closure of $A$ ($ cl(A) $).

$ int(A):=\{x\in X~|~\exists r>0 ~~s.t~~\Bbb B (x,r) \subset A  \}  $.

$ cl(A):=\{x\in X~|~\forall r>0 ~~~\Bbb B (x,r) \cap A\ne \phi  \}  $.

Properties;

(1) $ (int(A))^c =cl(A^c) $

(2) $ (cl(A))^c =int(A^c) $.

Proof)

(1) $ (int(A))^c $ = $ \{x\in X~|~\forall r>0~~\Bbb B (x,r) \nsubseteq  A  \} $=$\{x\in X~|~\forall r>0~~\Bbb B (x,r) \cap A^c\ne \phi  \} $=$cl(A^c) $

(2)  $ (cl(A))^c = \{x\in X~|~\exists r>0 ~~s.t~~\Bbb B (x,r) \cap  A=\phi    \} $
 = $\{x\in X~|~\exists r>0 ~~s.t~~\Bbb B (x,r) \subset A^c \} $=$int(A^c) $

ㅁ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties do hold, and your proof looks fine (though perhaps it could benefit aesthetically from some explanation between steps).

Another useful thing to talk about is the boundary of a set.  That is, we define
$\partial A=\{x\in X:\forall r>0, \mathbb B(x,r)\cap A \neq \emptyset \text{ and } \mathbb B(x,r)\cap A^c \neq \emptyset \}$.

See if you can find an alternate definition related to closures, interiors, and exteriors.